# median of groups in a DataFrame, Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, statistics

How can we compute the median of groups in a DataFrame?

Min, max, mean, etc. are part of spark.sql.functions, so we can do this:

df.groupBy("foo", "bar").agg(mean($"column1"))

However `approxQuantile` is part of DataFrame.stat i.e. a `DataFrameStatFunctions`.

Is there a way to use it inside the `.agg`?

Or do we need a user defined aggregation function?